# Yocto/BitBake Ignores Command Line Variable Overrides

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

In my local.conf I have the following variables defined:

```
MACHINE ?= "default"
# Version variables overriden by CI/CD
CI_COMMIT_BRANCH ?= "local"
BUILD_VERSION ?= "v0.0.0"
CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA ?= "local version"
```

In a recipe (custom-fit-image.bb) I use these variables:

```
python do_image_complete() {

    machine = d.getVar('MACHINE', expand=True)
    version_tag = d.getVar('BUILD_VERSION', expand=True)
    branch_type = d.getVar('CI_COMMIT_BRANCH', expand=True)
    git_short_hash = d.getVar('CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA', expand=True)
    bb.note(f"MACHINE: {machine}; BUILD_VERSION: {version_tag};CI_COMMIT_BRANCH: {branch_type};CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA: {git_short_hash}")
    ....
    ....
}
addtask do_image_complete before do_populate_sysroot after do_install
```

When I call bitbake from the cmdline I want to override them like this:

```
MACHINE=my_machine CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=bli BUILD_VERSION=bla CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=blub bitbake custom-fit-image
```

However only MACHINE get's overriden. Here the output of the bb.note call of the do_image_complete function:

```
NOTE: MACHINE: my_machine; BUILD_VERSION: v0.0.0;CI_COMMIT_BRANCH: local;CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA: local version
```

Why is only MACHINE overriden and how can I override the other variables?
The only difference I can see is that MACHINE is a standard yocto variable used in a lot of places and the other variables are my custom ones. But still they are defined in the same file and I try to override them in the same manner. So I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the bitbake manual at BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS:

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.4/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#passing-information-into-the-build-task-environment

You will see the default scripts/oe-buildenv-internal script sets BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS_OE to include MACHINE, DISTRO, TCMODE, TCLIBC, HTTP_PROXY, http_proxy and a few more.

Comment: Thanks! Running the following works for me:

**export BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS="$BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS CI_COMMIT_BRANCH BUILD_VERSION CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"**


`MACHINE=my_machine CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=bli BUILD_VERSION=bla CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=blub bitbake custom-fit-image`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Richard's response, add your custom variable too in `BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS`.

Add this in your `local.conf`:

```
export BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS="${BB_ENV_PASSTHROUGH_ADDITIONS} BUILD_VERSION CI_COMMIT_BRANCH CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
```

Comment: I think this does not work. In the bitbake manuel there is this note "You must set this variable in the external environment in order for it to work."

Comment: Yes, you have to export your custom variables too in that way you do not have to set these variables in command line while building your recipe. 
Instead of local.conf you can also use bbclass to do the same and inherit that in your recipe.